# How to prove that a transformed language is regular using an NFA

Tags: proof-explanation, automata, regular-language

I am trying to prove a transformed language `plus(L)`, which transforms a binary of an integer to a binary of `n+1`. So `plus(0111)` would be `1000`

I am trying to prove this by using the assumption that there is an arbitrary DFA that accepts the original language and by building an NFA that accepts this new language.

However, I am totally lost of how to do this. What is a good starting point, or what are the steps that I have to use to solve this kind of proof?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what this is asking.  Is `L` a given regular language, and then you want to prove `plus(L)` is also regular?  (In that case, I would expect the example to look more like `plus({0111}) = {1000}` .)  Or is `plus` somehow represented as a language itself - and in this case, how exactly are you identifying pairs of strings of binary digits with a set of strings over some alphabet?

Comment: @MJD Hmm, I don't see how it could be at all possible to write a mealy machine for this - unless it actually operates on *reversed* strings.  My interpretation of this would be what I suggested first - in which case, you could take the DFA for `L`, reverse all the arrows and the initial/accepting states to get an NFA for the reverse language, compose with the mealy machine for subtracting 1 from a reversed string, then reverse again.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sorry if it was unclear. The `L` is `{0, 1}*` (language that contains only 1s and 0s.

Comment: Just as a clarification what would be the value of plus("00111") ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with thinking about what strings are in this language from the smallest going up "1","10","11", "100", "101".  Then thinking if their are any patterns.

Well it looks like the first pattern "starts with one".  So from my start state I would have an arc tagged with "1" to a second state. Since "1" is a valid string in this language the second state is also a final state.

Then I would examine the strings after the first one has been consumed "0", "1", "00", "01", ... and I would see that by adding arcs from the second state back to itself that would match all of those states.

Comment: Sorry, but I am having a hard time following it. Is there a way to think it more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Construct a DFA that subtracts one from the input string. Then feed the output to the DFA that accepts $L$.

The following DFA starts with initial state $s_0=-1$ and subtracts $1$ from the
input sequence $u_k$.

That is, given a string $u=u_n u_{n-1} \cdots u_0 \in \{0,1\}^*$, with output $y=y_n y_{n-1} \cdots y_0$, then $v(y)=v(u)-1$ where $v$
is the binary value of the string parameter, and
$y$ is computed as
$y_k = \text{out}(s_k, u_k)$, $s_{k+1} = \text{next}(s_k, u_k)$
using the following table:

\begin{array}{|c|cc|}
\hline
s& \text{next}(s,u) & \text{out}(s,u)\\ \hline
-1& \bar{u}& \bar{u}\\ \hline
0& 0& u\\ \hline
1& \bar{u}& \bar{u}\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you but I am still confused. Usually I would prove this kind of question by proving that we start by stating that there is an arbitrary DFA that accepts the original language and show that there is an NFA that accepts the transformed L (plus(L) in this case). I cannot quite follow your answer.

Comment: If you have a DFA that accepts $L$, and you create a new DFA by composing it with the one above (that is, the output of the subtractor becomes the input to the $L$ DFA) with the $L$ DFA then the combined DFA will accept $\text{plus}(L)$.

Comment: So, is there no usage of NFA in this case?

Comment: Any DFA is an NFA.

Comment: In your example, I don't get how s0 can be -1 if the language is just composed of 0s and 1s. So, I am basically proving that `plus(L) = {plus(w) | w ∈ L }` is also regular.

Comment: This is a finite state machine. The state space can be any finite collection of objects, I used $-1$ as the initial state rather than $0$ because I am using the non initial state to represent the 'borrow'.